# How can i remove the value null of textArea

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

When i try to put the old value in textArea and she give me a space like in the screenShot.

```
<textarea name="commentaireTest" id="commentaireTest" cols="100" rows="3">
  {{$admission->commentaire}}
</textarea>
```

How can i enable or remove the space ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPfQT.png)

Comment: use php function trim() : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Try open and close tag in a single line. like, <textarea>{{$admission->commentaire}}</textarea>

Comment: Yes, Right answer .Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You've space between tag, remove it as below.

```
<textarea name="commentaireTest" id="commentaireTest" cols="100" rows="3">{{ trim($admission->commentaire) }}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need remove break by writing your `<textarea>` code like as below:

```
<textarea name="commentaireTest" id="commentaireTest" cols="100" rows="3">{{$admission->commentaire}}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<textarea name="commentaireTest" id="commentaireTest" cols="100" rows="3">
  {{ trim($admission->commentaire) }}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't give space before your old value.

```
<textarea name="commentaireTest" id="commentaireTest" cols="100" rows="3">{{$admission->commentaire}}</textarea>
```

Write code like that